# Find which of the following complex functions are continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hi I am trying to do the following problem

The functions $f_1(z)=\frac{\text{Re }z}{z},\,\,f_2(z)=\frac{\text{Re }z}{|z|},\,\,f_3(z)=\frac{z}{|z|},\,\,f_4(z)=\frac{\text{Re }(z^2)}{|z|^2},\,\,f_2(z)=\frac{z\,\text{Re }z}{|z|},\,\,$ are defined for $z\neq 0$. Which of them can be defined at the point $z=0$ in such a way that they are continuous at this point? Which of them are uniformly continuous?

I am very sorry to say that I tried a lot but couldn't even get how to start. Forgive my ignorance. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: In each of them try to look at what happens when $z=t$ (for $t$ real) and $z=it$ (likewise for $t$ real). Then you should be able to reach some conclusions.

Comment: @JeanMarie Any help....